# Get variable value defined in another python code

Tags: python

In order to create a code, I have decided to create a python class to just define some variables with default value. you can see this as "struct" in C.

the file is name : ScreenStructure.py

Inside I have defined this code

```
class ViewIdleScreen():
    def _init_(self):
        self.menu_access = "id/no_id/21"
        self.Call_app = "id/no_id/23"
        self.Email_app = "idno_id/24"
        self.Camera_app = "id/no_id/27"
        self.Browser_app = "id/no_id/26"
        self.Contacts_app = "id/no_id/9"
        self.Calendar_app = "id/no_id/10"
        self.Messaging_app = "id/no_id/11"
        self.Notes_app = "id/no_id/12"

    def Call_app(self):
        return self.Call_app
```

In the main file, I have added :

```
from ScreenStructure import ViewIdleScreen
```

later in the code of the main file:

```
IdleScreenView = ViewIdleScreen()
print IdleScreenView.Call_app()
```

but instead of displaying "id/no_id/23" it display

```
<bound method ViewIdleScreen.Call_app of <ScreenStructure.ViewIdleScreen instance at 0x02A16990>>
```

Comment: You've named the function and the attribute the same thing. You've also left out the **double** underscores around the `init` method, which means that's just a private method and not an initializer. Lastly, by convention, method names are lowercase in Python.

Comment: Looks like a good use for ```namedtuple()```.

Answer (score 3):

First, you're naming `__init__` `_init_`. This is wrong. You need two underscores.

Second, you're setting an attribute `Call_app` there, but that's the same name as the method you define later:

```
def Call_app(self):
    return self.Call_app
```

In addition to being shadowed by the attribute (if `__init__` were declared properly), this method returns the method itself, which is the `bound method` you're seeing.

Avoid the collision of attribute and method names, and name `__init__` correctly

Comment: ahh +1 better reading than me :P I thought it was strange that the method would shadow the member

Answer (score 0):

you should not make functions named the same  as data members

```
hello = "hello world"
def hello():
     print "goodbye!"

print hello
```

often times people will make a variable name preceded by an underscore or something

```
class X:
    def __init__(self,*args):
         self._x = "yellow"
    def x(self):
       return self._x
```

but as @mhlester points out a main problem is that you named `__init__` incorrectly